# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 occasionally crashes - How to diagnose?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, crash

About 2 months ago I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. About 1 month after using it without any problems I started suffering from sudden crashes. Everything freezes but the cursor works and the internet connection (streaming from twitch) and audio (can still hear twitch audio) works. Can't enter TTY either. I just have to reboot from hardware button. I had used Xubuntu for almost 2 years without such problems, and Windows10 works just fine.

The day this started happening I had removed 1 GNOME extension with rm rf ~/blabla/extension because it wasn't working and couldn't be removed normally. The extension was the system-monitor. I would think this has nothing to do with it.

/var/log/syslog part from around a crash I had earlier: https://pastebin.com/5LvZ8qX5

There is nothing on /var/log/kern.log from the time that a crash happened.

How do I diagnose what's wrong? (Tried to look for duplicates here, didn't find similar symptoms)

Comment: Search how to run a MEMTEST on your RAM.

Comment: Are you using FireFox? You could try Chrome or Chromium for awhile and see if the error reoccurs.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I was using Nouveau drivers, the default ones. I changed to nvidia proprietary drivers I downloaded from the website (.run file) and now it works.

So there is obviously a problem with the combination of GNOME(?)+NVIDIA GTX660 (other models?)+Nouveau

If you are facing the same problem, use nvidia proprietary drivers.